# need to call tool tips manually using tippedjs.com jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to use tippedjs.com jquery tool tips. but i have some specific requirement. Actually i want to call tooltips by click on button element. but this button element should show tooltips on any specified element. how to do it ?

```
 For example :
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test" >

    <input type="button"  value="Call tips">
```

Here i want that when we click on "call tips" button then tool tips should be show in test textbox.
Is it possible ?

Comment: `$('#test').mousemove();` should do it

Comment: No. i want to call when we click on button only. On button click event we can not use what you have given. because we have to use function provided in http://www.tippedjs.com/   i could not found any hint regarding how i complete my task.

Comment: I meant: `$(:button[value="Call tips"]').on('click', function(){$('#test').mousemove();});`  Now i don't know if there is anyway to call instead some plugin method, check DOC and see

Comment: i know about this jquery click event. but it will just attach that event with button but want to know about how to call tooltips in other element ?   As i told that i have already seen docs but could not found any hint and so i have asked this question in stackoverflow.

Comment: No it doesnt attach it , it triggers it... have you tested it???

Comment: have you used tippedjs.com ?

Comment: Ya and it is how i did it... i could post a jsfiddle but im actually on phone so...

Comment: if you did what i want then please add into jsfiddle when you get time.

Comment: thanks yaar... its done. actually i have to use mouseover events. I just change event name in your given suggestion.

Comment: <script>
     function myclickevent(id,str)
  {
    
          Tipped.create('#'+id, str, {   hideAfter: 1000 });
 
    $('#'+id).mouseover(); 
   
  //
  } 
      </script>

Comment: one question. I dont want to call alert on actual mouse over when i move cursor on textbox. Its ok if i call mouseover event from above function. Actually i want to show tooltips only from javascript and not from physical mouseover event. is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is what you need:

http://www.tippedjs.com/documentation#usage_api

---

**UPDATE:**

For some reason I'd tested the example above without success, but just reading the source code I came to this useful example:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    Tipped.create('.api-example', {
      size: 'x-small',
      showOn: 'click'
    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/tipped/4.0.10/css/tipped/tipped.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/tipped/4.0.10/js/tipped/tipped.js"></script>
<span class='api-example' title="1">One</span>
<span class='api-example' title="2">Two</span>
<span class='api-example' title="3">Three</span>
```